# Why is GaN better than Si as a substrate for ZnO thin film?

Tags: material-science, semiconductor-physics, optical-materials

in an attempt to grow a thin film using ZnO, I found many researches use silicon as a substrate and others use GaN. by further research I found that GaN is preferred than silicon but I don't know the reason. Why is GaN preferred over silicon?

Comment: Lattice mismatch perhaps?

Comment: I thought of lattice mismatch, but I think it may be that the energy band gap for GaN (3.4 eV) is much closer to that of ZnO (3.3 eV) rather than Si (1.1 eV). but I'm not sure about this answer, so do you agree with my opinion?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the device and application.

Comment: let a use of a ZnO thin film device to be a production of a UV random Laser light, then what will be the reason for my question?

Answer (score 2):

ZnO and GaN are both Wurtzite structure, with a very similar lattice constant; by contrast, Si is diamond cubic. Also, the thermal expansion coefficients of ZnO and GaN are very similar.

The following is taken from [this article by Hanada](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783540888468-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-692199-p173851917)

Lattice constants:

[image]

and coefficients of thermal expansion:

[image]

The corresponding numbers for Si are thermal expansion of $2.62\cdot 10^{-6}/K$ at 300 K [source](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd220.pdf) - significantly smaller - and lattice constant of 5.43 Å.

[added following a comment]: There is also the matter of the band bap. For Si, it is 1.12 eV; for GaN, 3.4 eV; and for ZnO, 3.2 eV. (all values depend quite strongly on temperature; these are not quoted at exactly the same temperature). Once again, GaN and ZnO are more similar - although I am not certain how relevant that is for the purpose of the question.

Over all, GaN is just a better match for ZnO than Si.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Can we also include the band gap similarity between both GaN and ZnO rather than Si?

Comment: I am not sure that the bandgap helps with the crystal growth, which is why I did not include it. But yes, I could add that information.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. This helps me very well.